# Migrating from ARM 5 to ARM 6 Compiler: Unknown type name '__STATIC_INLINE' in ARM CMSIS file

Tags: c, compiler-errors, arm

Currently migrating a large embedded C project in uVision from ARM 5 to ARM 6 compiler. The most persistent error is

```
error: unknown type name '__STATIC_INLINE'
```

which occurs in the core_cm4.h file which is provided by ARM which is read-only, hence I am hesitant to edit it. Nevertheless, I changed (under the CMSIS definitions, under `#if defined (__CC_ARM)`), the `#define __STATIC_INLINE static __inline__` by adding the two underscores after inline, as specified in the ARM 5 to 6 migration guide, but it still is not working.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely wouldn't touch that file. Instead, ensure you have the most up to date version of core_cm4.h, and use it as reference against your own.

The issue could stem from the ARM compiler being incorrectly installed, as __inline is an ARM specific keyword. Ensure all of your tool chain is correct, and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I had to select the CMSIS version 5.2.0, which was installed, but for some reason I was still compiling with CMSIS version 4.3.0, which caused the errors.